# Check if curl_easy_perform is successful

Tags: curl

Without using the GDB debugger, how can I find out if `curl_easy_perform()` returns successfully or not? It should return 0 if successful and non-zero if not successful.

I only have the executable, and running Ubuntu 14.04.

The symbol table looks like this ( `readelf -s FILENAME` )

```
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 14 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND curl_easy_init@CURL_GNUTLS_3 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND curl_easy_perform@CURL_GNUTLS_3 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND curl_easy_setopt@CURL_GNUTLS_3 (2)
     5: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
     7: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     8: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     9: 0000000000602050     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _edata
    10: 0000000000602058     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _end
    11: 0000000000400600     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _init
    12: 0000000000602050     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __bss_start
    13: 00000000004008f4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _fini
```

Running the executable is not indicative of the answer.

I know that curl is a tool to transfer data from or to a server via many protocols, but I'm unsure of how to dig into the return value of `curl_easy_perform()`. I know its successful if it can access the website or server, but I don't know what website it is trying to ping

Comment: And how do you expect to see the requested url and return value without using a debugger? Unless the executable outputs that information somewhere (console, file, etc), you need to use a debugger to see it. Otherwise, all you can do is use a packet sniffer to analyze the protocol data back and forth (which doesn't guarantee curl returns success even if it receives a successful reply from the server, if it runs into a memory error or parser error or the like).

Comment: I have ltrace, but the documentation doesn't help me in finding out how to use it